# colcon silently does nothing

Tags: ros, ros2, build, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

On

- Ubuntu 18.04
- I installed ROS Eloquant
- Followed this tutorial: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber/#pypubsub
- Everything was ok, until I reached the colcon build command.
- It was doing nothing, and gave no error, no message, verbose output was:

  ```
    $ colcon --log-level 10 build
    DEBUG:colcon:Parsed command line arguments: Namespace(build_base='build', continue_on_error=False, event_handlers=None, executor='sequential', install_base='install', log_base='log', log_level=10, main=<bound method BuildVerb.main of <colcon_core.verb.build.BuildVerb object at 0x7f8dc26f30b8>>, merge_install=False, paths='.', symlink_install=False, test_result_base=None, verb_extension=<colcon_core.verb.build.BuildVerb object at 0x7f8dc26f30b8>, verb_name='build', verb_parser=CustomArgumentParser(prog='/usr/bin/colcon build', usage=None, description='Build a set of packages.', formatter_class=<class 'colcon_core.command.CustomFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True))
    INFO:colcon.colcon_core.location:Using log path 'log/build_2019-11-14_16-30-55'
    [0.089s] INFO:colcon.colcon_core.executor:Executing jobs using 'sequential' executor
    [0.090s] DEBUG:colcon.colcon_core.executor.sequential:closing loop
    [0.090s] DEBUG:colcon.colcon_core.executor.sequential:loop closed
    [0.090s] DEBUG:colcon.colcon_core.event_reactor:joining thread
    [0.090s] DEBUG:colcon.colcon_core.event_reactor:joined thread
    [0.093s] INFO:colcon.colcon_core.plugin_system:Skipping extension 'colcon_core.shell.bat': Not used on non-Windows systems
    [0.093s] INFO:colcon.colcon_core.shell:Creating prefix script '/home/gdebrecz/works/dev_ws/install/local_setup.sh'
    [0.094s] INFO:colcon.colcon_core.shell:Creating prefix util module '/home/gdebrecz/works/dev_ws/install/_local_setup_util_sh.py'
    [0.095s] INFO:colcon.colcon_core.shell:Creating prefix chain script '/home/gdebrecz/works/dev_ws/install/setup.sh'

    $ echo $?
    0
  ```

with no error.
ROS package was not build. What am I doing wrong ?
thanks,
G

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337664/colcon-silently-does-nothing/) by [gdebrecz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49380/gdebrecz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-11-14**:
The fact that it uses the sequential executor indicates that you might not have installed all recommended `colcon` packages . Specifically `colcon-parallel-executor` seems to be missing. Can you share the output of `dpkg -l | grep colcon`.

**Comment by [gdebrecz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49380/gdebrecz/) on 2019-11-14**:
Hi !
Thanks for the answer !
Your command returns with:

ii  python3-colcon-core                             0.4.3-1                                      all          Command line tool to build sets of software packages.

Howevere, I followed the official ROS install guide and found no mention of need of installing other colcone packages.
thanks,
g

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-11-14**:
Can you please post a link which instructions you followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For that tutorial, a prerequisite is [Creating a workspace](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace/#ros2workspace) and for that tutorial a prerequisite is [colcon installation](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/#colcon) Which tells you to install `python3-colcon-common-extensions`

You don't clarify which installation instructions you followed. I suspect that you installed prebuilt binaries that don't need the build tools to run. There are different instructions for how to install ROS 2 to be able to run, versus being able to build.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gdebrecz](https://answers.ros.org/users/49380/gdebrecz/) on 2019-11-19**:
Thanks a lot for the help and pointers ! Indeed, I've overlooked that dependencies...my bad, sorry. After redoing the complete exercise everything works. Thanks again !